# OpenTelemetry Java Auto Instrumentation - Trace context changing when passing over multiple kafka topics

Tags: open-telemetry

I have a process flow like below between 3 Microservices using kafka as an event broker.

**`Service-1 (publish)-> (topic:1) ->(consume) Service-2 (publish)->(topic:2)->(consume) Service-3`**

For distributed tracing opentelemetry-javaagent.jar is used for auto instrumentation with jaeger as the backend.  During runtime the traces are disjointed and at any point in time trace correlation is only maintained between 2 services, as shown below

Service-1 produces with TraceId:1 and Service-2 consumes with TraceId:1 but when Service-2 tries to produce to Service-3 the TraceId changes(eg:TraceId:2) and Service-3 consumes with TraceId:2. Therefore for any service I could see only 2 spans.

Can someone help/guide here and let me know how to propagate the same trace context between all the 3 Microservices. The following versions are followed for binaries and kafka broker version is `2.12-2.8.0`

opentelemetry-javaagent.jar(version:1.18.0)
kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar
spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-kafka-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar

Thanks!

Comment: Figured out the problem as in the second service between the kafka consumer and producer ```(consume) Service-2 (publish)``` there was an async threadpool due to which the original traceid was not propagated instead a new one was created.

Comment: do you mind sharing a code example on how you solved this issue please

Comment: @austiine Unfortunately I can't share the code due to some compliance policies. As mentioned above the root cause was the thread context getting switched from the kafka listener thread to a separate thread pool. Hope this helps.